# How to combine two functions into one continuous function so it can be integrated/differentiated?

Tags: calculus, functions

I have a function like this :

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x \in)-\infty, 1)&,\;\;f(x)=x^2\\{}\\x\in(1,+\infty(&,\;\;f(x)=x^3\end{cases}\;\;\;\;\;\;$$

as you can see, the function as a whole is continuous. I wanted this as a single equation, with the same results. Is it possible? If yes, then how? Can there be a generalization to any given such functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do in this way:

$f(x)=x^2+[\Theta(x-1)](x^3-x^2)$

where $\Theta(x-1)= \begin{cases}0 \text{ if }\ x<1 \\ 1 \text{ if }\ x>1\end{cases}$ is the shifted unit step function.

Comment: Is there a general technique to do this?

Comment: how is this integratable, or defferetatable?

Comment: It is just another way of writing your original expression, if you want to compute a definite integral I suggest you split it

Comment: general technique? well, if you have a function F(x) that is f(x) for x<a and g(x) for x>a, you can write F(x)=f(x)+ $\ [\Theta(x-a)][g(x)-f(x)]$